# Regular expression get number

Tags: regex

I want to replace the following string with regex:

```
No. 1.
```

With:

```
<a name='1'></a>No. 1.
```

Where '1' can be a one or two digit number (eg 1,2,26,99)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: No, I don't understand regex and am stuck!

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a good information source.

Comment: Also, in what language/environment will you use this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the numbers are declared in the same way, this is easily done with JavaScript:

```
foo.replace(/No\. (\d+)\./, "<a name='$1'></a>No. $1.");
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed:

```
echo "No. 1." | sed "s#No\. \(\[0-9\]\+\)\.#<a name='\1'></a>\0#"
```